# Dompdf does not render custom fonts

Tags: php, yii2, dompdf

The $html string i send to dompdf gives me a good font when echo`ed.
I have already tried to :

- add fonts manually to dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts
- compile and save .afm and .ufm files to dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts
- uninstall and reinstall dompdf using file download and composer
- downloading dompdf\utils and running load_fonts script in cmd

Here is my code where i call dompdf

```
$options = new Options();
$options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$dompdf = new Dompdf('A4', $options);
$dompdf->loadHtml($html, 'UTF-8');
$dompdf->setPaper('A4');
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
```

Here is how it looks inside $html where i call my @font-face

```
<?php $link = yii\helpers\Url::base(true) . '/web/css/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf';
?>

@font-face {
   font-family: 'Roboto';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   src: url( <?php echo $link ?>) format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

First create **view.php** file in `views` and add `font-face` like

```
<?php $link = \Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/css/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf'; ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family:roboto;
                src:url(" <?php echo $link ?> ") format('truetype');
                font-weight:normal;
                font-style:normal;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="font-family:roboto">Sample Text Here</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** check load font file path is correct.

After load view file using [renderPartial()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#renderPartial()-detail) in `controller` and call [Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) like

```
public function actionPrintDemo() {
    $html = $this->renderPartial('view');
    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
    $dompdf = new Dompdf('A4', $options);
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html, 'UTF-8');
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4');
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately calling by getAllias gives me 
"Not allowed to load local resource:"